# llvm preprocessor g++ passes

Tags: g++, llvm, stage

Suppose I want to write my own preprocessor.

So I want something like this:

all *.cpp and *.hpp (even the included ones), before they go to g++, they go:

```
file --> my preprocessor -> g++
```

Is there a easy way to do this in the LLVM framework? i.e. to add in a stage that says: "after you load up the source file, pipe it through this program before compling it" ?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using llvm-gcc or clang? Also, do you mean that you want to somehow preprocess #include files before the compiler gets them (i.e. some kind of hook in the #include directive)?

Comment: I am willing to use either.

I want to have my layer called right before the standard #define macros are executed.

Comment: /* Requested tags: cpp preprocessor */

Answer (score 1):

Ideas:

1. Hack `cpp`. You can easily (`-no-integrated-cpp`) make `gcc` to call your version of `cpp` that will call real `cpp`.
2. Request `gcc -E`, collect the included filenames, read all that files with your program, removing "#include" lines.
3. Make prepreprocessor build step that will convert all files to intermediate form. *.cppanon -> *.cpp -> *.o; *.hppanon -> *.hpp;
4. Abandon idea of hooking "#define"s.
5. Create FUSE filesystem that will present filtered data to gcc.

Variant preference: 4,3,1,2,5.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would be very easy to make the Clang driver do what you want, although it does not have support for exactly what you want out-of-the-box.